# Generate animation in css3 as in the image into in container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to generate the animation that I describe in the image,

[image]

I hope to make myself understood. I'm building a video slider. At some point the user will click on a button, and I want to generate a displacement of the video, to the right getting lost in its parent container. And returning from the left without the user can see where it came from. I do not know if there is a more effective way to achieve it, I have tried but without result.

thank you very much.

http://jsfiddle.net/5bpa1x4L/

```
<div class='contendor_portafolio' class='next'>
 <video  id='video' width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
</div>

    #video{
      width: 98%;
      height: 100%;
      transition: all linear 0.5s;
      background:blue;
    }

    .next{
      display: block;
     /* opacity: 1;*/

     -webkit-animation: next 0.5s 1; /* Safari 4+ */
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes next {
      25% { 

        -webkit-transform: translateX(2000px);
       }
       50% { 
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
        display: none;
       }
       80% { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px)
       }  
      100%{
      } 
    }

    .contendor_portafolio{
        position: fixed;
        width: 84%;
        top: 10%;
        height: 80%;
        z-index: 91;
        left: 8%;
        text-align: center;
        opacity:1;
        background: green;
        transition: all linear 0.5s;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to be moving is the `video` ID not the `next` class.

```
#video{
   width: 98%;
   height: 100%;
   transition: all linear 0.5s;
   background:blue;
   -webkit-animation: next 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
}
```

and I slightly adjust the positions for a smoother exit and entry and changed it to infinite for a loop.

```
@-webkit-keyframes next {
   25% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateX(1700px);
   }
   50% { 
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
      display: none;
   }
   60% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-1700px);
   }
   100%{
   } 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, but how can I prevent the scroll bar from appearing on the x axis?

Comment: There shouldn't be, when I run it - there is none.

Comment: When the animation is executed, briefly appears the scroll bar, in the bottom part.

Comment: In which browser, I'm running Chrome and honest, there is none. Make sure you have the position is fixed because that is one aspect that prevents that from happening.

Comment: My idea was initially that the video passed under the container to the right. The scroll appears, in the instant in which the translation is fulfilled.

Comment: That link, is the original link XD

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Just a question, maybe you know. My idea at first, was that the video would go under the container and come back out at the beginning of the container ... is it possible?

Comment: You're welcome! I was sitting trying to figure that out, but I don't know. I am not an expert at CSS but I dont think there is. It'd probably involve JS but I'm no good with that either.